# Find corresponding value of variable B depending on value of variable A

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
set.seed(33)

df <- data.frame(
  x=as.character(sample(1:100, replace = FALSE)), 
  y=as.character(sample(1:100, replace = FALSE)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And I have a vector of a subset of variable x

```
ValuesColx <- as.character(sample(df$x,5))
print(ValuesColx)
```

[1] "10" "23" "43" "28" "27"

My goal is it to get a vector with the corresponding values of variable y.
My expected output would be:  c("1", "62", "83", "82", "70")

Comment: Why not do `Values <- df[sample.int(nrow(df), 5), ]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$y[df$x%in%ValuesColx];
## [1] "82" "70" "62" "83" "1"
```

Alternatively, and matching the order in your expected output:

```
df$y[match(ValuesColx,df$x)];
## [1] "1"  "62" "83" "82" "70"
```